# Linq , orderBy , and include

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-core

I have one to many relationships with these three entities :

```
class Tournamnet{
int Id 
string Name 
ICollection Games<Game>
},

class Game{
int Id 
int TournamentId
ICollection PlayerGames<PlayerGame>
}

class PlayerGame{
int Id
int GameId
int PlayerId
bool IsWinner
}
```

I want to get all data about a tournament, in a JSON format,

```
        public Tournament GetById(int id)
        {
            var tournament = tournamentTable
                .Include(tournament => tournament.Game)
                .ThenInclude(game => game.PlayerGame)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);


            return tournament;
        }
```

That is my Query, here every Tournament has a collection of games, every Game has two PlayerGames with one IsWinner = true and another IsWinner = false, I need to get PlayerGames ordered by GameId, how can I fix that ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get PlayerGames ordered by GameId, how can I fix that ...?

First make sure PlayerGames is a collection type that can be sorted.

eg

```
IList<PlayerGame> PlayerGames {get;set;} = new List<PlayerGame>()
```

Then just sort it after fetching from the database.

```
t.PlayerGames = t.PlayerGames.OrderBy(g => g.GameId).ToList();
```

Alternatively you could create a custom ICollection implementation that's always sorted by one of T's properties, but there's not one built-in and that seems like too much work for this.

Comment: While in general sorting in the database is better, it's just not simple in this scenario.  The way EF generates SQL for Includes, especially multiple includes makes specifying the sort in the query difficult, and potentially expensive.